# How to get correct NVD3 xAxis date

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I am expecting  to see '2013, 12, 16' on chart. But, I see 1970-1-16.

Where is wrong? [image]

1387212420 <-->2013, 12, 16, 8, 47

```
>>> timestamp3=1387212420
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp3)
datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 16, 8, 47)


var data = [{values: [
          {"date": 1387212420, "open": 163.86, "high": 164.39, "low": 163.08, "close": 163.95, "volume": 108092500, "adjusted": 163.95},
          {"date": 1387212430, "open": 167.11, "high": 167.61, "low": 165.18, "close": 167.44, "volume": 135592200, "adjusted": 167.44},
]}];

 var chart = nv.models.candlestickBarChart()
  .x(function(d) { 
      return d['date'] })
  .y(function(d) {
      return d['close'] })
  .duration(250)
  .margin({left: 75, bottom: 50});



 chart.xAxis 
      .axisLabel("Dates")
      .tickFormat(function(d) {

          return d3.time.format('%m-%d-%Y')(new Date(d))
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your timestamps are not compatible with Javascript's Date constructor. Try formatting them as ISO 8601.

```
new Date(1387212420);
// Sat Jan 17 1970 11:20:12 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time)
```

Comment: Like this: {"date": "2013-12-16T08:47:00"....? But, NVD3 chart does not draw properly. I think it expects integer timestamp. Not sure how to do it.

Comment: Please provide a JSFiddle/Plunkr to make it easier to replicate the issue.

Comment: Created a link. https://jsfiddle.net/x83ru1ta/8/. Not fully working, but structure is there.

Comment: How about you get it fully working first and then I can diagnose any issues? You need to correct the name of your wrapper div (it's chart not chart1) and include the NVD3 code. There doesn't appear to be any issue with the date processing code now.

Comment: This link is working (only issue, is should see 3 bars, but only 1 is shown) http://jsfiddle.net/9zfybvpk/20/

Comment: Make it .x(function(d) { return new Date(d['date']) })

You can't use strings as dates